# When did the Ethereum "free memory pointer" change? (6060... -> 6080...)

Tags: solc, compilation, bytecode, assembly

I have been digging a bit deeper into the Ethereum bytecode with the specific goal to do contract verification from the source code.

I noticed, while doing some tests, that the initial bytes of the Ethereum contract has changed somewhere between 0.4.21 and 0.4.22.

Normally, a contract would always start with:

```
6060604052
```

> PUSH1 0x60 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE

But starting at 0.4.22 and onward, they seem to start with:

```
6080604052
```

> PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE

What is the significance of this change, and where can I find documentation about this change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contract prologue instructions changed to provide an additional slot at 0x60, which should **always hold the value 0**. [The documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous.html) states that:

> The zero slot is used as initial value for dynamic memory arrays and
>   should never be written to (the free memory pointer points to 0x80
>   initially).

FYI I checked several contracts with [JEB Decompiler](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/jeb/evm), and it seems they agree with you: contracts with the old prologue (0x60 bytes) are detected as generated by Solidity <= 0.4.21, whereas contracts with the new prologue are detected as >= 0.4.22.

Comment: Very cool reference to the documentation. I also see that the sentence you quote was added to the docs specifically on 0.4.22. Last question I would have is "Why did this change?"

Comment: Most likely, for optimization purposes: if the compiler knows that the memory word at offset 0x60 is always 0, it can use that to optimize memory-array write operations during initialization or reset. My guess is that (some) constructs like "PUSH 0 / PUSH offset / MSTORE" (used to initialize [offset] to 0) can then be avoided. We would need to see that in code though. If you compile a non-trivial contract making use of memory arrays with a recent version of Solidity, you should be able to see how [0x60] is being used.

Comment: the documentation url format was updated, here are the links to 0.4.21 and 0.4.22.
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/miscellaneous.html
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.22/miscellaneous.html